# ANSI character not working for eclipse console on Ubuntu Linux

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu, character-encoding, ansi-escape

I am fairly new to Java and need your help. I am trying to change the color of the text in Eclipse console on run-time. I referred to one of the posts and tried to follow that. But the output shows a box of unicode escape character and the color of the text remains unchanged.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    System.out.println((char)27 + "[31mTest red color");
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

|00|

|1B| [31mTest red color

**Notes:**

1. For output, I couldn't upload the image so i have typed [001B].
2. The console uses UTF-8 encoding.

**UPDATE**
Following the comment from Jarrod for possible duplication of the question, here is my update - 
The question is mainly for ANSI character not working and not for text color, so i have updated the question.

Comment: What OS are you using? Those are ANSI escape sequences and don't work on every OS.

Comment: If you really want this kind of functionality, you should probably just build a GUI. Check out Swing and JavaFX.

Comment: Hi Kevin, Thanks for your reply! I use eclipse on Ubuntu Linux. I have not built any API but i will search and play around with Swing, JavaFX and see if it works.

Comment: Try using a ANSI-capable terminal, like gnome-terminal emulator. It works, but you are probably seeing the results from Eclipse output window, which does not support ANSI escapes.

Comment: @KevinWorkman apart from GUIs, having command line tools capable of colour output is a good thing in 2015.

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo If you say so. My only point is that since not every OS supports this functionality, you might be better off creating a basic GUI, if you really care about it.

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse does not support ANSI escape characters out of the box.
You have to install a plugin for that: https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/ansi-escape-console